# Cómo tomar fecha de fecha de hoy php?

Tags: dart

Lo que necesito saber es cómo puedo guardar en una variable, la fecha actualizada... La de hoy que me guarde la de hoy, manana la que corresponda y así sucesivamente....

Es para una app que dice las Farmacias que están de turno. Entonces guarde en la base de datos un string Fecha.

En la base de datos voy a guardar todas las farmacias con su correspondiente fecha de turno.

Cómo puedo consultar cada vez que se habrá la app la fecha?

Leí algo de podría sacar la fecha del servidor desde mi archivo php.

Alguien sabe como? Mi archivo php:

```
    <?PHP
$hostname_localhost="localhost";
$database_localhost="xxxxxxxx";
$username_localhost="xxxxxxxx";
$password_localhost="xxxxxxxx";

//declaro el uso horario
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$fecha = date("Y-m-d");


$json=array();


            $conexion = new mysqli($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost, $database_localhost);
            $consulta="select nombre,ruta_imagen,x,y,celular from farmacia where fecha ='{$fecha}'";
            $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

                while($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                $json['farmacia'][]=$registro;
                //echo $registro['id'].' - '.$registro['nombre'].'<br/>';
            }
            mysqli_close($conexion);
            echo json_encode($json);


?>
```

Este archivo lo que hace es devolverme la farmacia que este en la fecha asignada...

Answer (score 0):

lo otro que puedes hacer es tomar directamente la fecha con **date()** de php y guardarlo en una variable, hay varios formatos pero un ejemplo rápido puede ser algo así:

[Usos Horarios para php](http://php.net/manual/es/timezones.php)

`//defino antes el uso horario
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`

[Función date y formatos](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)

`$fecha = "date("Y-m-d");`

Al pasarle este formato y guardarlo en una variable si hago un *echo* me va a mostrar la fecha de hoy 2019-03-01, si lo ejecutas mañana va aguardar 2019-03-02, etc.

Para tu código quedaría así

```html
<?PHP
$hostname_localhost="localhost";
$database_localhost="xxxxx";
$username_localhost="xxxxx";
$password_localhost="xxxxx";

//declaro el uso horario
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

//mantengo el nombre para no modificar tus campos de fecha en las consultas
$fecha = date("Y-m-d");

$json=array();



 if(isset($_GET["fecha"])){

            $categoria=$_GET["fecha"];

            $conexion = new mysqli($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost, $database_localhost);
            $consulta="select nombre,ruta_imagen,x,y,celular from farmacia where fecha ='{$fecha}'";
            $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

                while($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                $json['farmacia'][]=$registro;
                //echo $registro['id'].' - '.$registro['nombre'].'<br/>';
            }
            mysqli_close($conexion);
            echo json_encode($json);

 }


?>
```

Comment: Sebastian, edite la publicacion, por que no me devuelve los datos, sino que devuelve " [] "